# How to modify method pattern to prototypal

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, prototype

Alright so how do I modify the following code from " Constructor pattern " to  Prototypal pattern ?
"  Modify Human to use prototypal design pattern when it comes to it's methods."

```
 const getName = function () {
     return "name: " + this.name;
   };
 const getNameAndAge = function () {
     return ("name: " + this.name + "  " + "age: " + this.age);
  };
 const introduce = function () {
     return (" Hello I am " + this.name)
 };
 const Human = function (name, age) {

 this.name = name;
 this.age = age;

 this.getName=getName;
 this.getNameAndAge=getNameAndAge;
 this.introduce=introduce;
    
 };
// test cases
//const human2 = new Human("Jane", 25);
// human2.getName();
// human2.getNameAndAge();
```

//-------------------------------------------------------------------
I am a student and I am currently learning JS -> Patterns,ObjectOriented and Inheritance.

Please feel free to give any sort of advice even if its not related to the main issue.
My code so far:

```
const getName = function () {
     return "name: " + this.name;
   };
 const getNameAndAge = function () {
     return ("name: " + this.name + "  " + "age: " + this.age);
   };
 const introduce = function () {                                                       
 
      };
 const Human = function () {
 this.name = name;
 this.age = age;
 this.introduce=introduce;
    
 };


 Human.prototype.introduce = function() {
     return ( "Hello I am " + this.name + " and I am " + this.age + " 
 years old" );
 }
 const human4 = new Human("lilly", 30);
 human4.introduce(); // => "Hello I am lilly"
```

Comment: Any suggestions :D ?

Answer (score 0):

Apperantly I needed to modify my code to look like this, I am getting correct output now, going to set as answered. Thanks

```
const getName = function () {
    return "name: " + this.name;
  };
const getNameAndAge = function () {
    return ("name: " + this.name + "  " + "age: " + this.age);
  };
const introduce = function () {
    // return (" Hello I am " + this.name)
};
const Human = function (name, age) {
this.name = name;
this.age = age;
// this.getName=getName;
// this.getNameAndAge=getNameAndAge;    methods removed
// this.introduce=introduce;
};
Human.prototype.introduce = function(){
    return "Hello I am" + " " + this.name;
}
//  const human2 = new Human("Jane", 25);
//  human2.getName();
//  human2.getNameAndAge();
```

const human4 = new Human("lilly", 30);
// human4.introduce(); // => "Hello I am lilly"